# Axios : fetch data of specific user

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I have the following hook in my React file :

```
  const [List, setList] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      axios
          .get("http://localhost:8000/api/profile/")
          .then((response) => {
            setList(response.data);
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

It get all profiles of the whole database. Then I display according to `user.id` the data of the specific user :

```
<ul>
<div>
    {List.map((item, index) => {
        if (
            item.user_id === user.id // Line where I'm displaying data according to the user.id after fetching all data
        ) {
            return (
                <li key={item.id}>        
                <div>              
                        {item.username}
                        </Link>  
                    </div>
                </li>
            );
        }
        return null;
    })}
</div>
</ul>
```

My question is, **how can I send custom axios request with the user_id and then display data of that user, instead of getting all data of the server and filtering it ?**

Comment: It's hard to say, because we don't know the API you're working with. Path, query, body parameters?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's an api generated by laravel. Rest.

Comment: That doesn't tell us what the actual interface is, though. Once you've found out, the Axios docs show a range of requests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I didn't understand your question.

Comment: What is api get detail user infor?

Comment: Well we don't know what request you'd actually have to make to get the data you want. It may not even be possible, we don't know. This is unanswerable as written, and if it was "how do I make <specific request> with Axios" you should really be reading the docs to find out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The request I'm making to the data is a `get`. When I'm typing  `http://localhost:8000/api/profile/` in postman, I receive a lot of arrays. Each array have a user_id for it. I would want to get the arrays of a user_id.

Comment: I don't know how many different ways I can tell you the same thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Forget about axios. How can I retrieve data according to a specific user_id in postman for example ? Key is `user_id`

Comment: **We. Don't. Know.** We don't have access to the backend you're using, so we can't tell you. It may not even _expose_ individual profiles. You will have to look at the implementation and/or read its API docs to find out. As I mentioned above, if it _does_ have a way to do that it will likely be a path, query or body parameter you pass the ID as.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are correct...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Riiight. Sorry I really misundertood what you meant. I don't know if this can help https://i.imgur.com/JnOPf9N.png

Comment: Given that that shows the request you're already successfully making, with the data you've already described, how could it? Random third parties on the internet (hi!) can't tell you how the API you have running locally on your machine (and wrote yourself?) works. If it was following REST conventions `GET /profiles` would give you all of them and `GET /profiles/<id>` would give you a specific one, but whether that works for your specific backend we cannot tell you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm really having a hard time understanding what you mean. English is not my first nor my second language. I'm making a simple request of the whole API and I'm getting all data available. What could be what ? I want to show NOT the whole data but only according to a specified user. I understand you said you don't know about the API, perhaps lead me to how I can know ? I'm actually reading axios docs and kinda lost.

Comment: There's absolutely no point reading the Axios docs until you actually know *what request you need to make* - they can only tell you how to make that request. We can't tell you what request you need to make, because we have no idea (beyond _"...api generated by laravel. Rest."_) what your backend actually is, so we don't know what endpoints and methods it exposes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my profile controller responsible of the api https://www.codepile.net/pile/w6J4WrkG

Comment: I've only briefly used Laravel, and I'm not pawing through code on some third party site. If you've written the backend I really don't understand why you don't know what it does. It seems pointless to continue this further.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my backend I have   `public function index(){$data = Profile::all();
return $data;}`  This returns information from a model named Profile that is linked to the table of profiles. This is where I'm getting all the data.

Comment: Ok, so what? That indeed seems to get all of the profiles, and you've already tested it's working. If you were expecting it to somehow also magically expose a single profile, it won't, you need to _write that endpoint too_. And if your question is "how do I write that endpoint", please see the laravel docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe THIS, is what I was getting wrong. I thought I will be having user_id if a specified something in the url directly. I need to actually send a request from Laravel requesting the user_id. Thank you very much man and sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm having a hard time as a newbie in Laravel and React.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that simply by adding params to get method, for ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
      axios
          .get("http://localhost:8000/api/profile/", {
             "user_id": yourUserId
           })
          .then((response) => {
            setList(response.data);
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

for more [details](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Note: your api must be rest and allow you to fetch user data via user id too, or if its in path just you need to add it:
axios

.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/profile/${userId}`)

Comment: Hokmat Abu Hmiad Yes my api is rest, it's created with Laravel. But your code doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: You need to validation it your api is build to allow you to fetch data fro specific user, you need to validated path, like last option, if its not exsits then you need to implement api first or try to find the api doc for it....get(http://localhost:8000/api/profile/${userId})...

Comment: My API is working fine, I tested with POSTMAN. But when testing directly your link in postman it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share you postman url here?, also you have an option to export api code like a js or curl...its will helpfull too...

Comment: That API is running locally on your machine, we can't make requests to it...

Comment: This url work and fetch all user list not only one user...so that how its fetch a specific user?